# how to refresh Window in extjs

Tags: extjs, window, refresh

I have one window in that I passed two dynamic `gridpanel`

1) FeaturGrid

2) gvpropertywn.

I want to refresh testWin (Window) how i can?

can u pls help me?

```
var testWin = new Ext.Window({
    id: 'resultwindow',
    title: LangVarTestWinText,
    width: 400,
    height: 300,
    layout: 'border',
    closeAction: 'hide',

    closable: true,
    //items:[FeaturGrid]
    items: [FeaturGrid, gvpropertywn]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `doLayout()` - I don't know if it will refresh the contents of the window, but it will redo the layout.

But my guess is that you might want to take a different approach to update the contents of your window. Please give more details to allow us to give you a better advice.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see both items are existant after rendering the window by your config

```
items:[FeaturGrid,gvpropertywn]
```

what exactly do you want to do ? if you remove any of the items in the window be sure you dont remove the one with region: 'center' defined otherwise when calling

```
doLayout()
```

the border layout will crash. if you add a new component and it doesnt popp up call

```
doLayout()
```

again